# If in cshtml to change style

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to know how can I get a **✔** to be located in a **si** or **no** in a form inside **C# MVC** that is defined by the value of a data in **SQL.**

I have this **PDF** form:

[image]

And what I need is that the **✔** is located in the **SI** or in the **NO** according to the value it has in the **DB**. When the value is **1 (one)**, the **✔** must go **SI**, but in case the value is **2 (two) or 3 (three)**, the **✔** must go **NO**.

The CSS to locate it I have done.

I tried to add this in the cshtml:

```
if (item.cobDomicilio == "1") {
    <p class="si">✔</p>
}else {
    <p class="no">✔</p>
    }
}
```

But, in this case that the value of the `cobDomicilio` is **1 (one)** the **✔** marks me in the **NO**. How can I solve that?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. There is no way for us to know what "the value of the cobDomicilio is 1 (one)" actually means. Please debug your code, figure out exact value and show it in your sample as part of the code like `item.cobDomicilio = "1 (one)"; if (....)` so there is no confusion on what you mean.

Comment: Can you paste the code for your page (the .cshtml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using HTML helpers you can do this

```
@Html.CheckBox("Si",true)
@Html.CheckBox("No",false)
```

If you are not using HTML helpers you can use Razor to help you build the *input-group* so that

```
<input type='checkbox' name='solicito' id='Si' checked />
<label for="Si">Si</label><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='solicito' id='No' />
<label for="No">No</label><br>
```